# Realization of time dependent neural network in keras using for-loop

Tags: python, keras, lstm, recurrent-neural-network

I have a recurrent model in keras that explicitly realized a for-loop over sequence. See model bellow [edited]

I have a large matrix input of size [samples~1M x time ~1k) and I need to use the same model which take as input a segment of that time neighbors ~ (-5,+5).

That writing seems:

1. Non-natural in term of Keras usage
2. for-loop might be inefficient and it is hard to tell the reason.

The question is: Should I and can I replace the use of for-loop within the model with something more built-in in keras layer? 
Will that also help in terms of speed?

If so, how will that being done, is the TimeDistributed keras model the correct approach? Couldn't figure out how to take running time segment with that model.

Thanks

```
def my_model(signal_length = 1000 ,pre = 5 ,post = 5, num_classes=4):

    # Define the input 
    X = Input(shape=(signal_length,))
    # output as a list of size (slightly less) as X
    outputs = []
    # sliding window on X, considering each segment as input
    for t in range(pre,signal_length-post):

    # per time unit consider the input signal of the neighboring ~10 signals:

        p1 = t - pre
        p2 = t + post
        Xt = Lambda(lambda x: X[:,p1:p2])(X)

    # Connect to network:
        Xt = Dense(20, activation='relu')(Xt)
        Xt = Dense(20, activation='relu')(Xt)
        Xt = Dense(num_classes, activation='softmax')(Xt)

    #output per unit time in a list:
        outputs.append(Xt)

    model = Model(inputs=X, outputs=outputs)
    mode.compile(optimizer='adam',loss='sparse_categorical_crossentropy',metrics=['accuracy'])        

    return model
```